# Is there a better way I can randomly reduce the number of my data-frame rows?

Tags: r

Please I have a triple class dataset that has 129 variables and about 58,000 observations (rows). My response variable has 3 classes: Attack, Natural, and NoEvents. The distribution of the classes is as shown below. However, I intend to reduce the "Natural" and "NoEvent" classes by 80% to enable me to create an imbalanced dataset but my code does not seem to work. Can some help me, please?

```
 > reduced<- sample_frac(powerData, powerData$marker=="Natural" & 
  powerData=="NoEvent",0.8)
 > 
 > table(powerData$marker)

 Attack  Natural NoEvents 
 40914    13351     3225
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple option that allows you great control...

```r
# dplyr 1.0.0
naturalsample <- powerData %>% filter(marker == "Natural") %>% slice_sample(prop = .2)
attacksample <- powerData %>% filter(marker == "Attack") %>% slice_sample(prop = .2)
noeventall <- powerData %>% filter(marker == "NoEvent")

# dplyr <1 use sample_frac(size = .2)

rbind(naturalsample, attacksample, noeventall)
```

Comment: Error in slice_sample(., prop = 0.8) : 
  could not find function "slice_sample". There appears to be nothing as "slice_sample"

Comment: Sorry you're running and older version of `dplyr` you can use `sample_frac(size = .2)` instead if you don't want to update